# Can't specify private key in SSH remote capture GUI in Wireshark v2.2.4-0-gcc3dc1b

Tags: ssh, remote, wireshark, capture

On the main UI screen of Wireshark (Windows), there is a **SSH remote capture** option in Capture section below Wireless & LAN options. While setting the options in the Extcap Interface options (by clicking the small black gear icon on the left of the options), I want to mention my private key for SSH. But no matter what file format I specify, the field stays red and the start button is grayed out. But if I specify a password instead it works. So how do I specify the private key? Is there some specific format etc.?

Comment: If you don't receive an answer here, I would suggest asking it at http://ask.wireshark.org or on the wireshark-users mailing list (subscribe at https://www.wireshark.org/lists/).  It may be that there's a bug in Wireshark that was fixed in master but not backported to 2.2.4.  In any case, the folks monitoring those sites will likely be better able to answer your question.

Comment: the same question was asked on ask.wireshark.org on Oct 7,2016 :       https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/56228/why-is-my-ssh-key-rejected-by-ssh-remote-capture            No response till now. So I asked here hoping someone would know something

Comment: OK, well I added a comment to the question so that it will trickle up to a more prominent position in the hope that someone who knows more about it will see it and can hopefully provide some help.  We'll see what happens ...